# Boost serialization of interface map

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, abstract-class

I have created a map of multiple different data types. s64, f64, Arrays, Images, etc.
To do so, i used a map of type `std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>> database;`.
I want to store it, and reload it from filesystem. But i heard that maps cant be sored in a one-liner. So i tried to store the data part `std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface> test;` of one pair first:

```cpp
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void    serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
        ar & test;
    }
```

The program crashes at `ar & test` throwing an exception: `"unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported"`.
whats the issue? i dont understand it.

here is the minimal code: (deleted)

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
//....
};
```

as 463035818_is_not_a_number pointed out, my sniped is not working.
i recreated it, and got a lot further i think. But as soon as i insert the load from file function, it does not compile anymore saying:
`error C2280: "std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)" : Es wurde versucht, auf eine gelöschte Funktion zu verweisen`

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class MapEntryInterface {
public:
    MapEntryInterface(std::string type_str) : type(type_str) {}

    std::string type;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void    serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
        if (type == "s64") {
            MapEntryS64* cast = (MapEntryS64*)this;
            cast->serialize(ar, version);
        }
        if (type == "f64") {
            MapEntryF64* cast = (MapEntryF64*)this;
            cast->serialize(ar, version);
        }
    }

};

class MapEntryS64 : public MapEntryInterface {
public:

    MapEntryS64(int init_val, const std::string& type_str)
        : data(init_val), MapEntryInterface(type_str)
    {}

    uint64_t data;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void    serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
        ar & type;
        ar & data;
    }

};

class MapEntryF64 : public MapEntryInterface {
public:

    MapEntryF64(double init_val, const std::string& type_str)
        : data(init_val), MapEntryInterface(type_str)
    {}

    double data;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void    serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
        ar & type;
        ar & data;
    }

};

class MapDataBase {
public:
    MapDataBase()
        //: test(std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>(new MapEntryS64(381, "s64")))
    {
        database["key1"] = std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>(new MapEntryS64(381, "s64"));
        database["key2"] = std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>(new MapEntryF64(3.124512, "f64"));
    };

    bool SaveToFile() {
        std::ofstream ofs("boost_export.dat");
        if (ofs.is_open()) {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
            oa & *this;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool loadFromFile() {
        std::ifstream ifs("boost_export.dat");
        if (ifs.is_open())
        {
            try
            {
                boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
                ia & *this;
                //std::string yolo;
                //ia >> yolo;
                //ia >> bam;
            }
            catch (std::exception& ex)
            {
                std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

private:

    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>> database;
    //std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface> test;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void    serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
        ar & database;
    }

};


void main() {

    MapDataBase tmp;
    tmp.SaveToFile();

    MapDataBase tmp2;
    //tmp2.loadFromFile();

}
```

Comment: the code you posted produces a couple of errors, but not the one you report: https://godbolt.org/z/e5vf1TqvY. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: you're right! the thing also is: the minimal sniped works... but i dont understand why its a difference to split it up into different files... i

Comment: do you have declarations and definitions of member functions in header and source? Definition of `MapEntryInterface::serialize` needs the `MapEntryS64`.

Comment: i edit the code in my question. you must be right, that the initial issue was caused by splitting the code into multiple files. now i have a compile error since i added the load function. looks like the load function, but does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a large amount of time making things self-contained. Among the many changes:

1. you should not have the base class serializing the derived (that's classic OOP), instead Boost expects derived classes to serialize their `base_object<>` (allowing static polymorphism and, incidentally, type registration)
2. of course, the base class *should* serialize its data members (`type`)
3. the base class SHOULD have a virtual destructor (otherwise deleting through `unique_ptr`'s destructor will be unspecified

   > Up till here:
   >
   > ```
   > class MapEntryInterface {
   >   public:
   >     virtual ~MapEntryInterface() = default;
   >
   >   protected:
   >     MapEntryInterface(std::string type_str) : type_(type_str) {}
   >     std::string type_;
   >
   >     friend class boost::serialization::access;
   >     template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& type_; }
   > };
   > using EntryPtr = std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>;
   > ```
4. The base/member initialize lists are in misleading order; initialization happens in declaration order anyways
5. The `type_str` is a code smell: the whole idea of OOP virtualization is **not** to have switching on types everywhere. I went half-way for you by at least defaulting the values, but you could probably do without it entirely. After all the type **is** the type.
6. Now add the `base_object` serialization:

   ```
   template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned)
   {
       ar& boost::serialization::base_object<MapEntryInterface>(*this);
       ar& data_;
   }
   ```
7. `MapDatabase` benefits from several simplifications

   - never use `new` or `delete`
   - checking the streams before is redundant since you already handle exceptions
   - since `loadFromFile` has no useful way of handling the exception, re-throw, or just let is escape,
   - also allowing you to make `MapDatabase` the return type instead of `bool`.
8. `saveToFile` and `loadFromFile` should probably take a filename parameter
9. Not shown: arguably `saveToFile` and `loadFromFile` need not be part of `MapDatabase`

At this point, adding a little bit of code to print database contents:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mpw9gyoz9bDV2CAv)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class MapEntryInterface {
  public:
    virtual ~MapEntryInterface() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream&) const = 0;

  protected:
    MapEntryInterface(std::string type_str) : type_(type_str) {}
    std::string type_;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& type_; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MapEntryInterface const& e) {
        e.print(os);
        return os;
    }
};

using EntryPtr = std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>;

class MapEntryS64 : public MapEntryInterface {
  public:
    MapEntryS64(int init_val = 0, const std::string& type_str = "s64")
        : MapEntryInterface(type_str)
        , data_(init_val)
    {
    }

  private:
    uint64_t data_;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar& boost::serialization::base_object<MapEntryInterface>(*this);
        ar& data_;
    }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "S64(" << data_ << ", " << std::quoted(type_) << ")";
    }
};

class MapEntryF64 : public MapEntryInterface {
  public:
    MapEntryF64(double init_val = 0, const std::string& type_str = "f64")
        : MapEntryInterface(type_str)
        , data_(init_val)
    {
    }

  private:
    double data_;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned)
    {
        ar& boost::serialization::base_object<MapEntryInterface>(*this);
        ar& data_;
    }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override {
        os << "F64(" << data_ << ", " << std::quoted(type_) << ")";
    }
};

class MapDatabase {
  public:
    using Map = std::map<std::string, EntryPtr>;

    MapDatabase() {
        database_.emplace("key1", std::make_unique<MapEntryS64>(381));
        database_.emplace("key2", std::make_unique<MapEntryF64>(3.124512));
    };

    bool SaveToFile(std::string const& filename) const
    {
        try {
            std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
            oa << *this;
            return true;
        } catch (std::exception& ex) {
            std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    static MapDatabase loadFromFile(std::string const& filename)
    {
        MapDatabase db;
        std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> db;
        return db;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MapDatabase const& mdb)
    {
        for (auto const& [k, b] : mdb.database_)
            if (b) os << std::quoted(k) << " -> " << *b << "\n";
            else   os << std::quoted(k) << " -> NULL\n";

        return os;
    }

  private:
    Map database_;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& database_; }
};

int main() {
    {
        MapDatabase tmp;
        std::cout << "------ tmp:\n" << tmp << "\n";
        if (not tmp.SaveToFile("boost_export.dat"))
            return 1;
    }

    MapDatabase roundtrip = MapDatabase::loadFromFile("boost_export.dat");
    std::cout << "------ roundtrip:\n" << roundtrip << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
------ tmp:
"key1" -> S64(381, "s64")
"key2" -> F64(3.12451, "f64")

unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported
```

### `unregistered class` runtime error

The message says it all: at time of deserialization, there is no information about the types that can be deserialized. Add that:

```
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(MapEntryF64)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(MapEntryS64)
```

Now it prints

```
------ tmp:
"key1" -> S64(381, "s64")
"key2" -> F64(3.12451, "f64")

------ roundtrip:
"key1" -> S64(381, "s64")
"key2" -> F64(3.12451, "f64")
```

### Several Translation Units

In the case of separate translation units, split the class export macros as per the documentation. E.g. the class export macro ends up doing

```
#define BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(T, K)                                  \
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY2(T, K)                                          \
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(T)                                        \
/**/
```

So, naively (taking another half-hour to split it all op sensibly:)

- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "MapDatabase.h"
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       {
           MapDatabase tmp;
           std::cout << "------ tmp:\n" << tmp << "\n";
           if (not tmp.SaveToFile("boost_export.dat"))
               return 1;
       }

       MapDatabase roundtrip = MapDatabase::loadFromFile("boost_export.dat");
       std::cout << "------ roundtrip:\n" << roundtrip << "\n";
   }
  ```
- File `MapDatabase.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include "MapEntryS64.h"
   #include "MapEntryF64.h"
   #include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>

   class MapDatabase {
     public:
       using Map = std::map<std::string, EntryPtr>;

       MapDatabase();

       bool SaveToFile(std::string const& filename) const;
       static MapDatabase loadFromFile(std::string const& filename);

       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, MapDatabase const&);

     private:
       Map database_;

       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& database_; }
   };
  ```
- File `MapDatabase.cpp`

  ```
   #include "MapDatabase.h"
   #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <iostream>

   MapDatabase::MapDatabase() {
       database_.emplace("key1", std::make_unique<MapEntryS64>(381));
       database_.emplace("key2", std::make_unique<MapEntryF64>(3.124512));
   }

   bool MapDatabase::SaveToFile(std::string const& filename) const
   {
       try {
           std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
           boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
           oa << *this;
           return true;
       } catch (std::exception& ex) {
           std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
           return false;
       }
   }

   MapDatabase MapDatabase::loadFromFile(std::string const& filename)
   {
       MapDatabase db;
       std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
       boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
       ia >> db;
       return db;
   }

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MapDatabase const& mdb)
   {
       for (auto const& [k, b] : mdb.database_)
           if (b) os << std::quoted(k) << " -> " << *b << "\n";
           else   os << std::quoted(k) << " -> NULL\n";

       return os;
   }
  ```
- File `MapEntryF64.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include "MapEntryInterface.h"
   #include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

   class MapEntryF64 : public MapEntryInterface {
     public:
       MapEntryF64(int init_val = 0, const std::string& type_str = "f64");

     private:
       uint64_t data_;

       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
           ar& boost::serialization::base_object<MapEntryInterface>(*this);
           ar& data_;
       }

       virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override;
   };

   #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(MapEntryF64)
  ```
- File `MapEntryInterface.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <iosfwd>
   #include <string>
   #include <memory>
   #include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

   class MapEntryInterface {
     public:
       virtual ~MapEntryInterface() = default;
       virtual void print(std::ostream&) const = 0;

     protected:
       MapEntryInterface(std::string type_str);
       std::string type_;

       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar& type_; }

       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, MapEntryInterface const&);
   };

   using EntryPtr = std::unique_ptr<MapEntryInterface>;
  ```
- File `MapEntryS64.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include "MapEntryInterface.h"
   #include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>

   class MapEntryS64 : public MapEntryInterface {
     public:
       MapEntryS64(int init_val = 0, const std::string& type_str = "s64");

     private:
       uint64_t data_;

       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
           ar& boost::serialization::base_object<MapEntryInterface>(*this);
           ar& data_;
       }

       virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override;
   };

   #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(MapEntryS64)
  ```
- File `MapEntryF64.cpp`

  ```
   #include "MapEntryF64.h"
   #include <ostream>
   #include <iomanip>

   MapEntryF64::MapEntryF64(int init_val, const std::string& type_str)
       : MapEntryInterface(type_str)
       , data_(init_val)
   {
   }

   void MapEntryF64::print(std::ostream& os) const {
       os << "F64(" << data_ << ", " << std::quoted(type_) << ")";
   }

   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(MapEntryF64)
  ```
- File `MapEntryInterface.cpp`

  ```
   #include "MapEntryInterface.h"

   MapEntryInterface::MapEntryInterface(std::string type_str) : type_(type_str) {}

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MapEntryInterface const& e)
   {
       e.print(os);
       return os;
   }
  ```
- File `MapEntryS64.cpp`

  ```
   #include "MapEntryS64.h"
   #include <ostream>
   #include <iomanip>

   MapEntryS64::MapEntryS64(int init_val, const std::string& type_str)
       : MapEntryInterface(type_str)
       , data_(init_val)
   {
   }

   void MapEntryS64::print(std::ostream& os) const {
       os << "S64(" << data_ << ", " << std::quoted(type_) << ")";
   }

   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(MapEntryS64)
  ```

Prints: **[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mrx70lPpcKhnFimV)**

```
------ tmp:
"key1" -> S64(381, "s64")
"key2" -> F64(3, "f64")

unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported
```

### UHOH Are We Doomed?

Not at all. Just need to [read the documentation closely](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#:%7E:text=then%20no%20code%20will%20be%20instantiated):

> `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` in the same source module that includes any of the
> archive class headers will instantiate code required to serialize
> polymorphic pointers of the indicated type to the all those archive
> classes. If no archive class headers are included, then **no code will
> be instantiated**.

So, adding the includes:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(MapEntryF64)
```

(and the same for `MapEntryS64`):

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tyxCzWgRJfDlLVLr)**

```
------ tmp:
"key1" -> S64(381, "s64")
"key2" -> F64(3, "f64")

------ roundtrip:
"key1" -> S64(381, "s64")
"key2" -> F64(3, "f64")
```

### BONUS: Simplicity

I prefer simplicity. I would probably replace all of the above with:

- File `MapDatabase.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <map>
   #include <boost/variant.hpp>

   namespace Database {
       struct Nil { void serialize(auto&, unsigned) {} };
       using S64   = uint64_t;
       using F64   = double;
       using Entry = boost::variant<Nil, S64, F64>;
       using Map   = std::map<std::string, Entry>;

       std::string_view typeOf(Entry const&);

       void SaveToFile(std::string const& filename, Map const& m);
       [[nodiscard]] Map loadFromFile(std::string const& filename);

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Nil);
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Map const&);
   } // namespace Database
  ```
- File `MapDatabase.cpp`

  ```
   #include "MapDatabase.h"
   #include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace Database {
       std::string_view typeOf(Entry const& e) {
           assert(e.which() < 3);
           return std::array{"Nil", "S64", "F64"}[e.which()];
       }

       void SaveToFile(std::string const& filename, Map const& m)
       {
           std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios::binary);
           boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
           oa << m;
       }

       Map loadFromFile(std::string const& filename)
       {
           Map                           db;
           std::ifstream                 ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
           boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
           ia >> db;
           return db;
       }

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Nil) { return os << "NULL"; }
       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Map const& m)
       {
           for (auto const& [k, v] : m)
               os << typeOf(v) << "\t" << std::quoted(k) << " -> " << v << "\n";
           return os;
       }
   } // namespace Database
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "MapDatabase.h"
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       SaveToFile("boost_export.dat",
                  Database::Map{
                      {"key1", 381ul},
                      {"key3", {}},
                      {"key2", 3.124512},
                  });

       std::cout << Database::loadFromFile("boost_export.dat");
   }
  ```

Printing **[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5HJxz1PjMHDbRjQe)**

```
S64 "key1" -> 381
F64 "key2" -> 3.12451
Nil "key3" -> NULL
```

Comment: Added a BONUS alternative using `variant<Nil, S64, F64>` instead which zaps the code into ~ 60 lines (https://wandbox.org/permlink/5HJxz1PjMHDbRjQe)

Comment: This is truly insane! 
It took me some time to realy dig into everything you posted here. But i read and tryed out everything. 
Thank you so much! Your solution is fantasic. Needed to update SDK and boost to even compile every c++17 stuff which was inserted. I'm kind of new on 17, or even 11 and 14. But things seem to get even nicer, while look a little unfamilier at first.

Comment: Cheers. In case it helps: [c++14 version (not using `auto` args, structured bindings, CTAD and std::string_view)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kxjlrNX868D3RDKn),  [c++11 version (just not using `std::quoted`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jk2O4Mft3tFDTytk), and [c++03 version (not using `auto`, ranged-for, std::array, uniform initializers](https://wandbox.org/permlink/v2BCHUpM2dOLQbeJ)